# Read directory then insert to sql

Tags: php, mysql, directory

For some reason I am just dumb with arrays... I cannot figure them all the way out... All I want to do here is read a folder and get all the folder names inside of that folder and insert them into a mysql db. Now the db part isn't my problem. Its handling this array. I did something similar in an earlier project, and now I cannot figure out how to modify it to work here.

```
<?php 
$main_folder = 'C:/Users/Oval Office/Music/'; 
$folders = glob($main_folder, GLOB_ONLYDIR); 

$artists_names = array(); 
foreach($folders as $folder){ 
    $artists_names[] = preg_split('/(.+)\s(\d+)/', str_replace($main_folder, '', $folder), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);  
} 

$values = array(); 
foreach($artists_names as $pair){ 
    $values[] = "('".$pair[0]."')"; 
} 

$query = 'INSERT INTO artists (title) VALUES '.implode(',', $values); 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
echo ($result) ? 'Inserted successfully' : 'Failed to insert the values';
?>
```

The Title Is Just Blank...

Thank you pekka for stearing me in the right direction, post it as a answer so I can give ya some rep.

Comment: What is the question, what doesn't work?

Comment: It prints that the Query was ran succesffull and that info got inserted into the DB, but when i go check the Title is empty...

Comment: What does `$values` contain? Does anything get processed in the foreach that builds it? Is `$artists_names` an array?

Comment: @pekka that looks like the problem, i jsut echo'd it and it printed `('')` how would this be done right? it worked on another project i had.

Comment: Then work your way up doing test outputs until you find the problem. Maybe nothing gets glob()d in the first place

Comment: i dont really understand what glob is used for, someone else wrote the glob part for me on my other project. lmao vote down for trying to get help, at least say something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the wild-card is missing.

Try this:

```
$main_folder = 'C:/Users/Oval Office/Music/*';
```